# Angular - pass a component property in (onclick)

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-data

**Is it possible to pass a variable of a component A, in the `(onclick)` on an element in component B like below ?:**

> Component B:

`<comp-A (click)="NodeClicked({{index}})"> </comp-A>`

Where `index` is a variable of the component A.

Comment: Can you please describe relation between component A and B? Whether there is any parent child relationship or not? It would be nice if you can share complete templates and components which is in your mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to pass the variable from the child (Comp-A) into the parent component (Comp-B) I would suggest using the [Event Emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).  An example can be viewed at the bottom of the page.

When a button is clicked from within the child the event will emit to the parent and you can use that data as desired from there.